# way to declar multiple @oneToMany in same entity to avoid org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Unable to perform un-delete

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-onetomany

I have been working with the code, here you people can see that I've used two @oneToMany for two different entity for this reason, it showing me the error of **"org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Unable to perform un-delete for instance"**
I was looking for a solution then I come to see the following post-
[org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Unable to perform un-delete for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778785/org-hibernate-assertionfailure-unable-to-perform-un-delete-for-instance) 
the post is vary useful to understand my problem but solution is not clear. Here first solution is but he or she just said-
 " Rearranging the code so that I first remove the references from C to A and then proceed to delete both B and A seems to work around this."
But how?????

Here is my code, I think it's enough

```
@Entity
@Table(name="c")
public class C extends BaseEntity{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5610744565502850451L;
    private String cCode;
    private String cTitle;
    private String cOverview;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private UserEntity userEntity;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cEntity",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<LeEntity> leEntity;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cEntity",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<LaEntity> laEntity;
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle properly bidirectional @OneToMany relation you need to keep both sides in sync so that one parent is deleted child does not keep it and when child is deleted parent deletes it too.

This concept is well explained here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many

Comment: i've figure out the problem. To solve the problem instead of using mappedby we've to use @joinTable annotaion